# Hashing vs composite PK to identify if it is an object having attributes which are unique(as a combination)

Tags: java, sql

Requirement : To create a new ID if the combination of attributes does not exist and reusing the ID if the same combination is found.

Two approaches I could think of is using hashing and then bounding an ID to the hashCode.

OR

using composite PK to check if a row is distinct or not.

What could be the best way to handle it keeping in mind performance and memory.

For Ex.

```
class Lens{
   String axis;
   String cylindrical;
   String spherical;
   float height;
   float width;
   String package;

    ...... and few more
}
```

Suggestions for any other approach appreciated.

Comment: How do you plan to generate the hash code? You will have to use composite PK to use it as a key. So why take an extra step. Use composite primary key

Comment: I can generate using SHA256. I can bind a new ID to a new hashcode but not as composite PK. I cannot have composite PK because I will be searching based on hash only.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest hashing instead of composite PK mainly because of below reasons:

1. If in future you want to add any other key in hashing you can do it without changing db table query and changing db table query to add new column in composite PK could end up effecting your previously stored data.
2. If you use hashing you can validate data before storing by comparing your hash with already present hash in DB but if you are using composite PK you will get the error for duplicate data at the time of storing.

Moreover, I guess performance and memory will not effect that much for both the approaches.